# How can I set the date format to my country setting?

Tags: time, format, date

I am German, but I use only English software. Hence, I am also using English Ubuntu. It's not because I don't know how to install German Ubuntu. It's because I prefer to work with English software environment. However, I would like to keep date & time format in German format, just as I use a German keyboard layout in English Ubuntu.

I can set the time format to 24h time. But how can I set the date format to German time format? It is irritating for me to have the day number before the time numbers:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bfSLc.png]

In other words, instead of "Oct 14 15:16"
I want it to display "14 Okt"
or (if only English language is available) "14 Oct 15:16"
or "14th Oct 15:16".

At least, the number of the day should be displayed before the month. In Windows, it was no problem to choose time/date/currency settings according to a chosen country.

Where can I do this in Ubuntu? 
The best would be if I could freely enter the date/time format myself with variables (DD.MM hh.mm.ss etc).

I found answers for Ubuntu 11.04, but not for Ubuntu 12.04.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit.

Keep in mind that I am a beginner. So I'd like to be able to do this via GUI, if possible.

---

EDIT:
**I found the answer in a forum.**

1. **Go to *System Settings...* and choose *Language Support***. There are two tabs, *Language* and *Reginal Formats*. You are by default on the *Language* tab.
2. On the *Language* tab, **click *Install / Remove Languages***.
3. A window with a list of languages opens.
4. **Mark the language(s) you want to add** for your time/date/currency format.
5. **Click *Apply Changes***.
6. **Ubuntu will now download and install the additional language files**, as well as help files of other applications in this language. So don't be irritated.
7. When Ubuntu has finished applying the changes, **switch to *Regional Formats*** tab. (Do not change the *Language for menus and windows* on the *Language* tab if you only want to change the date/time/unit format).
8. There you can **choose from the dropdown list the language for your preferred format** for date/time/currency/unit.
9. **Log out and log in** again to have the changes take effect.

Comment: Exactly. As your answer is much more detailed than mine, I would suggest to remove your edit, place it as an answer and accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to change the time format to German , you must install the German language from the Language Support and then set the "Regional Settings" in German

[image: languagesupport]

[image: languagesupport2]

If you want to change the format in Date and Time , you must install dconf-tool . From terminal do

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Find it through Dash by writing **dconf** open it and goto Com > Canonical > Indicator > Datetime and from there you can change the format.

[image: Date-time]

Logout and Login for changes to take effect.

The default format is `%l:%M %p` , you will change it to `%M:%l %p`

[image: datetime]

Comment: Changing custom-time-format in `dconf-editor` didn't affect the date shown in the panel, even after logging in again. At least `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` ends up showing only `%H:%M`, even if `show-day` is enabled.

Comment: `time-format` has to be set to `custom` for `custom-time-format` to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date and numbers display according to your country in Settings > Language support (not sure about the exact wording of this option as my version is not in English).